# Function which is zero on the boundary of smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I know that this exercise is a standard one for smooth partition of unity, but my manifolds are very rusty (would dare to say that they aren't smooth anymore). So please, help my with it:

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with non-empty boundary $\partial M$. We are given a smooth real function $h: M \mapsto R$ and closed set $D \subset \mathrm{int} M$. Show, that there exists a function $ g: M \mapsto R$ such that:

- $g(x) = h(x)$ in $D$
- $g(x) =0$ on $\partial M$

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following lemma : for any disjoint closed set $A,B \subset M$, there is a smooth function $f$ which is identically zero on $A$ and identically $1$ on $B$. Existence of your function follows by taking $A = \partial M, B = D$, the desired function is $g := hf$.

How to obtain such function $f$ ? It is classic (hint : partition of unity) that for any closed set $A \subset M$ there is a positive function $\theta_A$ which vanishes exactly at $\theta$. Now, $f = \frac{\theta_{A}}{\theta_A + \theta_B}$ vanishes exactly at $A$ and is identically $1$ at $B$.